# How to exit a program?

Tags: ocaml

If the input argument are not as expected I want to exit the program. How should I achieve that? Below is my attempt.

```
let () =
  if ((Array.length Sys.argv) - 1) <> 2 then                                                                                                                                              
    exit 0 ; ()                                                                                                                                                                           
  else
    ()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`exit n` is a right way to exit program, but your code has a syntax error. `if ... then exit 0; ()` is parsed as `(if ... then exit 0); ()`. Therefore you got a syntax error around `else`, since it is not correctly paired with `then`.

You should write:

```
let () =
  if ((Array.length Sys.argv) - 1) <> 2 then begin                                                                                                                                           
    exit 0 ; ()                                                                                                                                                                           
  end else
    ()
```

or simply,

```
let () = if Array.length Sys.argv - 1 <> 2 then exit 0
```